# Prorogate a custom error in PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to refactor my existing app in order to add support for PassportJS, but it's getting more difficult than expected.

I'm using **passport-jwt** as strategy. So I have

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options, user.verify));

router.post(
  '/login/jwt', 
   passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false, failWithError: true})
);
```

And if *user.verify* fails it calls (for example)

```
done(new Error(errors.BAD_REQUEST));
```

But I have no way to handle this error, whatever I pass as first parameter of the *done* callback, Passport always sends a **401 - Unauthorized** response.

This is not what I expect since I have many error handlers in my codebase and I want to communicate a meaningful error to the client.

I googled a lot so far, and I opened several SO questions besides the [official documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs#custom-callback), but any of those solutions fixes my problem.

For example, a common solution for this problem is using a closure in order to access req and res objects (as the link above), but this is not applicable to my existing app.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I assume you want to help the user and say the password is incorrect for example.

In the 'Verify Callback' Section you can find this example:

`return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });`

And by default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status

To catch this message you could try something like this: 
http://passportjs.org/docs#custom-callback

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Does this help?

---

Edit: With no IIFE

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failWithError: true }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    // Handle success
    return res.send({ success: true, message: 'Logged in' })
  },
  function(err, req, res, next) {
    // Handle error
    return res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: err })
  }
)
```

Comment: This would work, but as I said above I'd prefer to don't use closures since the *verify* method is in another section of my application, and it's also used by other functions, so I should refactor a lot of code in order to change it and anyways it would ruin the structure do not keeping the concerns separate. Really are there no other solutions?

Comment: I also tried to hack it calling .bind({req, res, next}) and accessing it through this.req, this.res and this.next, but this is a mess since I transform my function in a middleware which returns a middleware. Not exactly an elegant code

Comment: Hey, would this help you: [Documentation for failWithError option #458](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/458)?
See code edit